# Laravel 5.2 multi-dimensional field form phpunit tests

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5

I'm using laravel/phpunit tests and I would like to test a multidimensional form, this fields below works well except when I'm testing.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="practice_options[{{$diff}}][tries]">

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="practice_options[{{$diff}}][questions][easy]">

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="practice_options[{{$diff}}][questions][easy]">

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="practice_options[{{$diff}}][questions][easy]">

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="practice_options[{{$diff}}][time_limit]">
```

This is my test:

```
$input = [
            'practice_options[easy][tries]' => "1",
            'practice_options[easy][questions][easy]' => "10",
            'practice_options[easy][questions][medium]' => "7",
            'practice_options[easy][questions][hard]' => "3",
            'practice_options[easy][time_limit]' => "300"
        ];



        $this->actingAsAdmin()
                ->visit('/courses/1/practice')
                ->submitForm(trans('admin::layout.save'), $input);
```

But dont works I get this error in tests

**InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "practice_options"**

Please help how to make test with multidimensional fields to pass

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, the crawler dont recognizes if you open a form in @section and close in another @section in same page.

In my specific case, because of layout I open a form in Header @section and my submit button was also in this section, and I create my fields in the below section and close the form.

I put all in the same section and worked, crawler founds all !